# Redux - Store doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am a novice in Javascript and Redux, and I just created my first app based on this [tutorial](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/todos). I have a problem that the Store absolutely doesn't react to any dispatch call. I don't know if there is an error in the connection between Redux and React or in the store configuration itself.

Could you please help me with this problem?

This is snippes from my actions file where "addTodo" action is defined.

```js
export const ADD_TODO = 'ADD_TODO';


let todoId = 0;

export const addTodo = (text) => ({
    type: ADD_TODO,
    id: todoId++,
    text,
});
```

Below is my Store configuration.

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';
import DevTools from '../containers/DevTools';

const enhancer = compose(
    applyMiddleware(createLogger),
    DevTools.instrument()
);

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, enhancer);

    if (module.hot) {
        module.hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
            const nextRootReducer = require('../reducers').default;
            store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
        });
    }

    return store;
}
```

My index file where I try to call a dispatch function with "AddTodo" action creator. Similarly, I call this function in Redux containers, but it doesn't work for both.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import configureStore from './store/configureStore';

import { addTodo } from './actions';

const store = configureStore();

store.subscribe(() =>
  console.log(store.getState())
);

store.dispatch(addTodo('test'));
```

The whole project is placed on [Github](https://github.com/jezikk/redux-test) too. I will be thankful if you help me.

Comment: you should try reducing this to a reproducible example (the react component, for example, isn't relevant here) aka an MVCE

Comment: Yeah,You have absolutely right. I've made some code simplifications.

Comment: Have you been successful in getting the app to work, using the original react/redux tutorial code - before making your modifications?

Comment: Yes, but this one I write from scratch. I think the code is almost the same as in the tutorial. I think It may be an error in project settings, but I don't see any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to invoke createLogger, try

```
const enhancer = compose(
    applyMiddleware(createLogger())
   ...
);
```

**[webpackbin test](http://www.webpackbin.com/E1dplwjP-)**